# Instead of toggling a Jquery-Selectable on and off, how can I add another toggle option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been scouring the web for a solution on how to do this, but I'm not getting an leads at all. Some of the terms keep overlapping with others; (e.g. HTML-Select, Adding-Options, Jquery-MultiSelect). I figured it's something common too, at least posted on some blog, but even that is tricky to find.

**The Issue:**
I wanna be able to add a class to the Selectable rotation in a JQuery Selectable. Right now the rotation as most of us know is just toggling "ui-selected" on/off. [There is ui-selecting, but I'm just referring to the end result]. But ultimately, what I'm trying to do is add an additional grouping. (e.g. "None-Selected", "Selected-with-a-click", "selected-with-two-clicks"). So when I do serialize it to my application, i could have two lists to send.

```
    //Note: Not the real syntax for color styling
    <li class="hlight ui-selectee"/> *No Click*
    <li class="hlight ui-selectee ui-selected" style="blue"/> *One Click*
    <li class="hlight ui-selectee ui-alt-selected" style="green"/> *Two-clicks
```

**The Research:**
So far what I've found or been playing with is binding a click action to control this.

```
    $('.hlight').bind("click",(function(){ alert($(this));});
    $('.hlight').click(function(){alert("Print Something plz!");});
```

However these aren't firing off in code or the browser console.

Then I found out about "Selected", so I tried the following... [but in the end, alters how "unselected" works, and skips a phase `if item.hasClass("ui-selected")` usually always.]

```
    $(function() {
            $('#selectable').selectable({
                filter:".hlight",
                selected: function(event, ui){
                    var item = $(ui.selected);
                    if (item.hasClass('ui-alt-selected')){
                        item.removeClass('ui-alt-selected');
                        item.removeClass('ui-selected');
                    } else if (item.hasClass('ui-selected')){ 
                            item.removeClass('ui-selected');
                            item.addClass('ui-alt-selected');
                        } else { 
                             item.addClass('ui-selected');
                        }
                }});
        });
```

I will admit I'm fairly new to using jquery so much, and have a snitch of understanding of it's practices. How would I be able to add an extra class to a jquery selectable rotation, and what would be the most ideal way to this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I kind of gave up on the whole trying to manipulate Jquery Selectable widget to have click-through options.

What I ended up doing is letting JQuery modify the line-items (li) for on-clicks. Even to this moment, I'm still not sure if Selectable JQuery Widget deactivated click features, or possibly just occupied it and didn't let me override the function.

My Solution:

```
    //Honestly, I'm pretty confident this isn't needed. Leaving it as a reference.
    $('#selectable').selectable({ 
        filter : ".hlight"    
        disabled : true,
    });

    //What I do have in code
    $('.hlight').on("click",fucntion(){
        if( !$(this).hasClass('ui-selected') && !$(this).hasClass('ui-alt-selected')){
            $(this).addClass('ui-selected');
        } else if( $(this).hasClass('ui-selected') ){
                $(this).removeClass('ui-selected');
                $(this).addClass('ui-alt-selected');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('ui-selected');
                $(this).removeClass('ui-alt-selected');
            }
    });
```

and of course the styling (CSS)

```
    .hlight :hover {background-color:lightblue;color:white;}
    .ui-selected {background-color:orange;color:white;}
    .ui-alt-selected {background-color:red; color:white;}
```